# Saving a textbox autocompletecustomesource

Tags: c#, winforms

So, att I have the following....

```
        textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.NetworkIP;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection sc = Properties.Settings.Default.IPList;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sc;
```

And..

```
        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Contains(textBox1.Text))
                textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

And..

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection sc = Properties.Settings.Default.IPList;
        sc.Add(textBox1.Text);
        Properties.Settings.Default.IPList = sc;
        Properties.Settings.Default.NetworkIP = textBox1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

The saving/restoration of NetworkIP is working fine.
Saving & restoring IPList is working fine.
Small problem.
Pressing either Enter or TAB after editing textBox1 only resilts in the contents of textBox1 being highlighted with the cursor sitting at the end.  I have to physically click on the next field to move the cursor on.

Commenting this out allows TAB but not Enter to work OK but of course I don't get the save...

```
            AutoCompleteStringCollection sc = Properties.Settings.Default.IPList;
        sc.Add(textBox1.Text);
        Properties.Settings.Default.IPList = sc;
```

Users being what they are, how does one delete an entry in the dropdown?

Your assistance is appreciated.

Ian

Comment: you need to create the object yourself.. the class is AutoCompleteStringCollection. on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm bit confused whether you are interested in saving `Textbox` selection or `AutoCompleteSource`, assuming you need to store [`Specialized.StringCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) (IPList or an updated IPList), I have following snippet that might help to fix your case.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection source = textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource;

if (Properties.Settings.Default.IPLIST != null)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.IPLIST.Clear();
    Properties.Settings.Default.IPLIST.AddRange(source.Cast<string>().ToArray());
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: Hi Hari.  No offense.  Just thought Sean's solution might have been easier to implement.  I presume your routine goes in textBox1_Leave?

Comment: whether this logic goes in `textBox1_Leave` or any other event is implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can store the autocomplete entries as a AutoCompleteStringCollection by changing the setting type to System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection

```
        AutoCompleteStringCollection sc = Properties.Settings.Default.autoComp
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sc;
        sc.Add("new option")//or whatever you want
        //set the setting
        Properties.Settings.Default.autoComp;
        //save it to file
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: HI Sean,  This would seem to be the easier way to go but I don't seem to have a "System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection" user setting.

Comment: What dev environment are you using? Or how are you creating your settings file.

Comment: Hi Sean,  Visual Studio 2015 C#.  Using the app.config settings via Project | Properties | Settings..  I am just learning VS & C#.

Comment: I use the same IDE. I found these instructions that work. http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2013/08/19/windows-forms-saving-user-s-additions-to-autocomplete-textbox-source.aspx Follow the first couple steps to be able to use AutoCompleteStringCollection.